# Handle concurrent futures in two vectors?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to write a function that handles a collection of futures concurrently and returns `values` and `errors` after they become available.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to conquer the syntax here. This is where I am:

```
async fn handle_futures<I, T, E>(futures: I) -> (Vec<T>, Vec<E>) where I: IntoIterator<Item = impl Future<Output = Result<T, E>>>, { // <- this line errors
    let mut futures = FuturesUnordered::from_iter(futures);

    let (mut successes, mut errors) = (vec![], vec![]);

    while let Some(result) = futures.next().await {
        match result {
            Ok(value) => successes.push(value),
            Err(error) => errors.push(error),
        }
    }

    (successes, errors)
}
```

I'm currently seeing this error:

> `impl Trait` only allowed in function and inherent method return
> types, not in bound

Could someone help me land on a working implementation?

**Edit:** I think this did the trick:

```rust
async fn handle_futures<I, T, E, P>(futures: I) -> (Vec<T>, Vec<E>)
where
    P: Future<Output = Result<T, E>>,
    I: IntoIterator<Item = P>,
{
    let mut futures = FuturesUnordered::from_iter(futures);

    let (mut successes, mut errors) = (vec![], vec![]);

    while let Some(result) = futures.next().await {
        match result {
            Ok(value) => successes.push(value),
            Err(error) => errors.push(error),
        }
    }

    (successes, errors)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use anonymous type parameters (a.k.a. [`impl Trait`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/impl-trait.html#anonymous-type-parameters) in argument position) syntax here, as nesting them inside trait bounds is not supported. Use a plain old generic type parameter for your future types instead:

```
use futures::prelude::*;
use futures::stream::FuturesUnordered;

async fn handle_futures<I, T, E, U>(futures: I) -> (Vec<T>, Vec<E>)
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = U>,
    U: Future<Output = Result<T, E>>,
{
    let mut futures = FuturesUnordered::from_iter(futures);

    let (mut successes, mut errors) = (vec![], vec![]);

    while let Some(result) = futures.next().await {
        match result {
            Ok(value) => successes.push(value),
            Err(error) => errors.push(error),
        }
    }

    (successes, errors)
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=60f81c60fb84fcc41474fdf7b706194d)

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce another generic parameter for the future:

```rust
async fn handle_futures<I, Fut, T, E>(futures: I) -> (Vec<T>, Vec<E>)
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = Fut>,
    Fut: Future<Output = Result<T, E>>,
{
    // ...
}
```

Or, if you prefer, you can constrain `I::Item` directly:

```rust
async fn handle_futures<I, T, E>(futures: I) -> (Vec<T>, Vec<E>)
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Future<Output = Result<T, E>>,
{
    // ...
}
```